# Android app: Update UI of some item views in a GridView

Tags: android, user-interface, gridview

I have an Activity that hosts a GridView. When the Activity is resumed, in the OnResume method, I want to update the UI of **some** item views (but not all) of the GridView because their underlying data has changed. I know that the GridView has the `invalidateViews()` method, but that is overkill because it recreates all views. In my case, I just want to update some views.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: How about `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: You need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().This must be called after refreshing the views.

Comment: I'm using a custom adapter and a custom layout. Looks like calling notifyDataSetChanged() is not enough. Do I need to do anything in my custom views to receive notification from notifyDataSetChanged() in order to update my views?

Answer (score 1):

After changing the data of gridview call adpter with notifydatachanged() after that only it update the gridview with fresh dara

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

If you use invalidate views it will create view again

Comment: It doesn't work. Calling this method doesn't update my views.

Comment: did you checked weather data is changed before data assign to gridview

Comment: actually, notifyDataSetChanged() is only available from the ArrayAdapter class. I'm not using that class. I'm using a custom adapter. Is there an equivalent to that?